Nested reuse of Composable function & DI
Assuming a datamodel like this:
data class TreeItem(
    val id: String,
    val parentId: String,
    val title: String
)

Now I need to represent a tree level per screen, so I build a composable function doing this
@Composable
fun ListScreen(id: String) {
    val vm = getScreenModel<MyScreenModel> { parametersOf(id) } // getScreenModel is a KMP version using voyager, similar to koinViewModel
    val state = vm.state.collectAsState()
    // this is a dummy implementation which isn't 100% working like this, but the idea should become clear
    ListRepresentation(state.items) { id ->
        navigateTo(ListScreen(id))
    }
}
@Composable
fun ListRepresentation(items: List<TreeItem>, onItemClick: (id: String) -> Unit) {
    LazyColumn {
        ...
        items(items) {
           // ... some ui calling the onItemClick callback if clicked
           
        }
    }

}

I have 2 problems with that, which I am not sure how to solve nicely.

Scrollstate - the scrollstate is the same on every screen. How can I avoid this?
DI acts funny.
koin-android is doing the job and creates a viewmodel per parameter
voyager is not doing it, its returning the inital instance (using a factory here is not nice, but works - may be I should report this to voyager github issues.)

Are there any patterns for this scenario already? If so I would like to see them.
Are there any DI patters for this scenario?
